# How to merge arrays from documents in aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Assuming there is a collection where each document contains an array `a`:

```js
[
  {
    a: [ { x: 1 }, { y: 1 } ]
  },
  {
    a: [ { z: 1 } ]
  },
]
```

How can I use aggregation to get the documents contained in the arrays as result:

```js
[
  { x: 1 }, { y: 1 }, { z: 1 }
]
```

I read many similar questions, but I just can't figure this one out. Note that the most outer square brackets indicate the pipeline result array, not an array within a document.

Answer (score 1):

As so often, just formulating the question already helps.
Turns out I was thinking too complicated.

It's simply:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$a"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$a"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/P2zHrbBlseu